# ImageTexture shows digonal border?

Tags: texturing

I'm an absolute beginner in using blender.
What I want to achieve is applying an image texture to a plain rectangle.
The result shows a pattern along the diagonal. How can I avoid this?
My image "Texture.png" does not show this diagonal struture.

[image]

I generate the shading as follows:

[image]

Regards Christophe

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi Christophe. Please edit your question ad add more information. What does the real texture look like? What the UV map of the plane look like?

Comment: looks like a UV issue to me, how do they look like?

Comment: I added the sample file
[here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/N5RaejKV/)

Comment: I solved it myself, by looking at the UV Map. And I removed all structures there.

Answer (score 0):

Look how your UV looks like, for some reason it's not the same as your original shape, this deformation explains why the inner triangulation of your quad appears (a quad is always made of 2 triangles, if you deform the face or the UV you'll begin to notice it):

[image]

To fix that you need to unwrap again, you can do a simple <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap* or *Project from View* and the texture will be correctly displayed:

[image]